# Angularjs footer loading before content

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to have my header/footer wait to load until my content has loaded with Angular?

Right now when my page loads you see the header and footer first for a few seconds. Then the content is loaded. Can I fix that?

Here is the set up:

```
<header>
<content> **ui-view**
<footer>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could put a ng-show="vm.loaded==true" on your header and footer and in your controller have that set to false at startup, then when you content is loaded change that to true.

Comment: It's better to load something as soon as possible rather than wait several seconds to load everything. I would add a spinner. If you are experiencing a several second delay in development, imagine what it would be like on a slow mobile internet connection in production.

Comment: It is on regular mobile internet. I was just wondering if there was a way to counteract it. I would prefer the footer not show up as the thing that people see first. Does that make sense?